# Javascript и системный терминал

Tags: javascript

Могу ли я достучаться до системного терминала из js, сделать там mkdir, ls и т.д.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Очень хочется ответить вам: "НЕТ! ЭТО НЕВОЗМОЖНО И ОПАСНО!" Но прогресс не стоит на месте, и есть такая штука, как "FileSystem API". Эту возможность поддерживает только Google Chrome. Во всяком случае по состоянию на 2013 год.

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

Также надо учесть, что это API дает доступ только к файлам в песочнице, то есть с реальной файловой системой вы взаимодействовать не будете.

Если очень хочется что-нибудь посохранять  на компьютерах пользователей, смотрите в сторону LocalStorage ([подробный обзор здесь](http://html5-demos.appspot.com/static/html5storage/index.html)).

Comment: мне хочеться вызвать "rails g ..." у себя, используя лишь js (не спрашивайте зачем :-p). Кстати, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: @Денис Сергійович, этим должно заниматься веб-приложение, развернутое на той же машине, которое и будет тянуться через js.

Comment: Через node можно это делать.
http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback
Огромное вам спасибо, погуглил filesystem api, и все решилось. )

Comment: ну node.js - это серверное приложение. То есть, опять же, на клиенте вы по факту ничего путного не насохраняете. В случае же если у вас и сервер, и клиент - это одна машина, то тут, конечно, возможны варианты.